# ConcurrentNavigableMap vs NavigableMap differences

Tags: java, collections

There are some additions to the Java Collection Framework.

I tried to find out but I could not drill down what is actually the difference between:
**NavigableMap** vs **ConcurrentNavigableMap**.

Is it only, that ConcurrentNavigableMap can be modified by different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is that `ConcurrentNavigableMap` provides the additional `ConcurrentMap` methods to `NavigableMap` as well as the additional concurrent usage semantics of `ConcurrentMap`.